# Save Form Data Temporarily in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am building a form that allow users to save their data temporarily and complete later.

My problem is there are some Session variables that are used in the database, and so no column for them. The sql runs, and quits when the column is not found.

Is there a better way to implement what I'm trying to achieve?

```
foreach ($SESSION as $key => $value) {
    $userInput1 = "UPDATE userform SET $key=:value WHERE username=:username AND email=:email" ;
    $userInput2 = $dbusage->prepare($userInput1);
    $userInput2->execute(array(
    ':value' => $value, 
    ':username' => $_SESSION['username'],
    ':email' => $_SESSION['email']
    ));
}                        
if($userInput2->errno)
{
    echo "An Error Occured".$userInput2->error;
}else{
    header('Location: profile.php');
    $userInput2->close();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You could just store `serialize($_SESSION)` in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column `saved_session` to the table. Then serialize the whole `$_SESSION` variable and store it there.

```
$stmt = $dbusage->prepare("UPDATE userform SET saved_session = :session WHERE username=:username AND email=:email");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':session' => serialize($_SESSION);
    ':username' => $_SESSION['username'],
    ':email' => $_SESSION['email']
));
```

Then when they come back, you get it out and do

```
$_SESSION = array_merge(unserialize($row['saved_session']), $_SESSION);
```

Comment: Thank @Barmar for the quick answer. Very right on point in every level. Achieved what I wanted to achieve. Wow you are the boss.